# How to check for file existence in the "google drive folder" and download the file in "Google Drive Folder" after the confirmation popup

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to add a code in my exisiting script to pave its way for finding the existing files in the selected Google drive for by **getFolderbyId** command, what so ever the file is of any kind the program should check and upon having files on Google Drive folder it would popup a message "There are already files stored in this folder, would you like to continue anyway?" then upon pressing yes button the files by url list would be downloaded to the Google drive folder.

I've made this script by **DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);** command, so Please it is requested to edit or suggest code with this **ById** command. I'd also be very much glad if you guys could fix the "task has been completed" syntax as it is not working after the completion of all the loops and the after the whole function.

Code is given below:

```
    function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
    .addToUi();
}

function showAlert() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
var result = ui.alert(
    Please confirm ',
    Are you sure you want to
    continue ?
        if so then please make sure that your drive folder is completely empty ',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
// Process the user's response.
if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    {
        let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
        let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        for (let i = 0; i < lastRow - 2; i++) {
            const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            const folder_id = ss.getRange("Sheet1!J4").getValue(); // get value in "Settings!C9"
            const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)

            let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);
            let url = sheet.getRange(3 + i, 1).getValue();
            let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url);
            let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
            let name = sheet.getRange(3 + i, 2).getValue();
            folder.createFile(blob).setName(name);
            sheet.getRange(3 + i, 3).setValue("Completed");
        }
        ui.alert("task has been completed")

    };

} else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Permission denied.');
}
}
```

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask a question.   What is your issue exactly do you have an error?

Comment: @DaImTo, I just wanted to ask that how can I check existance of files in a folder of which I'm using the folder id in the above code and and then execute the function after the confirmation popup of yes or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example will list all the files with in a folder.  You can then test on say the file name and mime type to detect if the file already exists.

```
function main(){

  var name = "Untitled spreadsheet"
  var type = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  var folderId = '1bUTP9uKOpPpsn-UrOH0QEF6v2g3qhMGx'

var exists = FileExists(folderId, name, type);

if(exists){
  console.log("File Name exits of this mimeType")
}else {
  console.log("File Name does not exist of this mimeType")
}

}


function FileExists(folderId, name, mimeType){  
 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); 
  
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    
    console.log(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getMimeType())

    if(file.getName() == name && file.getMimeType()== mimeType ){
      return true;
    }    
  } 

  return false;
}
```

Comment: @DalmTo Thankyou so much it worked, but I wanted to use get files as an argument instead of a file's accurate name finding but I made it done by editing your written code for which I'm really thankful to you